# Automatically adding/removing checked exceptions while prototyping

Tags: java, prototyping, checked-exceptions

I would rather not add/remove `throws` clauses manually, especially while prototyping.  Is there a batch refactoring tool that adds/removes `throws` clauses to every method to reflect the code?  After all, the compiler tells you what exceptions a method may throw, therefore maybe a tool exists that uses that information to manipulate `throws` clauses.

EDIT: Before I clarified that I am looking for a batch tool, somebody has mentioned a manual intervention via IDE, but this is not what I am looking for.  I am looking for a batch utility.

Comment: You need them just as much then as any other time. Saves you writing unimplementable crap, for one thing.

Answer (score 1):

[ProjectLombok](https://projectlombok.org/) has a **wonderful** feature called [SneakyThrows](https://projectlombok.org/features/SneakyThrows.html) 
(It may fit your use case in prototyping.)

From their website you can do the following without a compile error :

```
@SneakyThrows(UnsupportedEncodingException.class)
public String utf8ToString(byte[] bytes) {
  return new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
}

@SneakyThrows
public void run() {
  throw new Throwable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use your IDE to add checked exceptions to your method unless you intend to handle that exception.  This way you code won't be a mess when it comes to production-ising it. i.e. you don't have to think about it, just let your IDE do the work.

In IntelliJ, I select the line which has a checked exception and hit `<Alt>` + `<Enter>` as I do to fix most errors and select `Add exception to method signature` which can also add it to any method overridden as well.

Comment: >  just let your IDE do the work.

This does not seem the case, as I must click on every line.  I am looking for an automated tool.

Comment: @Elena how many lines are we talking about? there shouldn't be more than dozens.